# Display active Main Menu and sub Menu using CSS and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have left side menus.

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading panel-red" role="tab" id="headingDash" style="">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapseDash" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseDash" class="menuList" style="">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard" style=" padding: 15px;color: #fff"></i>
            Dashoboard
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseDash" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingDash">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="subMenuList active" style=" ">
                    <a href="#" style="">Dashboard-1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="subMenuList" style="">
                    <a href="#" style="">Dashboard-2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to display active main menu and sub menus. On-click of sub menu using css and JS.
I have done it for static main menu and sub menus.

**My Fiddle link:** https://jsfiddle.net/whv76xd0/6/

How can do this dynamic on click?

[**Working Fiddle link**](https://jsfiddle.net/whv76xd0/47/)

Comment: what you want to acheive through dynamic click?

Comment: @Arvind: Enable main menu and sub-menus like : Fiddle **Dashboard** and **Dashboard-1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".subMenuList", function(){
        $('.panel-heading').removeClass('panel-red');
        $('.subMenuList').removeClass('active');
      $(this).closest('.panel').find('.panel-heading').addClass('panel-red');
      $(this).closest('.panel').find('.panel-heading').removeClass('panel-head');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    })
})
```

Comment: @Pavan if it solve your problem, please mark the this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

@pavan, If you want to handle dynamic link of submenu, then try with below jQuery function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".subMenuList",function(){
      alert();
    })
})
```

Here, instead of alert you can put, any functionality which you want to perform with submenu click event